# Need to export drupal comments to disqus

Tags: drupal-6, comments, export, disqus

We want to implement disqus commenting system in our existing drupa6 site.we have installed disqus module and configured well and working fine.

but we have 200k comments  in my drupal comments table.we need to export them to the disqus but we am not getting any sample xml format or any tool to export the comments.
we are unable to export them in a single attempt because the no of comments are 200k.
could some one please help me to export comments into disqus.

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 1):

There is a Ruby script that can do this for you.

- Download [this](https://github.com/pichot/drupal6-to-disqus-xml) project from [GitHub](https://github.com).
- Read the README.md file; you'll need to provide your MYSQL database info in config.example.
- Run the script. If your comments output above 45MB, it will even split the xml for you.
- Go to [Disqus->Import](http://import.disqus.com/), select your domain and import the XML. Make sure to select the correct format.

<strike>For a Drupal 7 solution, use a [Disqus Migrate](http://drupal.org/sandbox/dwkitchen/1483518) module. You'll need to check it out with Git and install it as a Drupal module.</strike>

### Update

For Drupal 7, [Disqus Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/disqus_migrate) module is now stable. Install it like any other module.

Comment: Note that the [Disqus Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/disqus_migrate) module is now a full module, not a private sandbox module.

Comment: @geerlingguy - thanks for the heads up. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you´ll have to wait until D7, because the next version of the Drupal module has the possibility to export comments into Disqus.